# Running Mkbootstrap for DBI () => DBIXS.h:22:20: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory

Tags: perl, docker, dbi, alpine-linux

I try to install MHA node on a docker container based on Alpine. The container has perl, make and gcc via apk. :

```
RUN apk add --update perl make gcc
```

A prerequisite for MHA node is DBD::mysql. The command

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql'
```

results in the above given error. Google does know nothing about it.

The following commands, needed for MHA manager, do run fine, however:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Config::Tiny"
perl -MCPAN -e "install Log::Dispatch"
perl -MCPAN -e "install Parallel::ForkManager"
```

The problem obviously is related to DBI:

```
Running Mkbootstrap for DBI ()
chmod 644 "DBI.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Perl/g" ./Driver.xst > Perl.xsi
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap "/usr/share/perl5/core_perl/ExtUtils/typemap" -typemap "typemap"  Perl.xs > Perl.xsc && mv Perl.xsc Perl.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Os -fomit-frame-pointer   -DVERSION=\"1.636\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.636\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE"  -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wno-comment -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter Perl.c
In file included from Perl.xs:7:0:
DBIXS.h:22:20: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:625: recipe for target 'Perl.o' failed
make: *** [Perl.o] Error 1
  TIMB/DBI-1.636.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

What can I do to resolve it?

Works with Ubuntu 14.04 after install make gcc

Answer (score 2):

You need the libperl headers to be able to build certain modules, including DBI. On Alpine it looks like they are provided by the package `perl-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=486526

> EXTERN.h is part of the perl C API which is needed for embedding the interpreter and building XS modules. The official perl distribution contains all these files, but many linux distributions don't bundle it as part of the base perl package (some even leave out a lot of core modules). There should be one or more additional packages for your distribution that supply the C API files. They're usually called "perl-*dev*" or something like it. (From googling, it looks like the mandrage package is "perl-devel-5.*.rpm")

So the solution looked like to add perl-dev to the apk add command, but this was not enough:

```
In file included from DBIXS.h:23:0,
                 from Perl.xs:7:
/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE/perl.h:699:23: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:628: recipe for target 'Perl.o' failed
```

Ok, some more googling resulted in addin musl-dev as well. Now that works:

```
FROM alpine

ENV MHA_NODE_VERSION=0.54 \
    MHA_MANAGER_VERSION=0.55

COPY ./mha/* /tmp/
# mha4mysql-manager-0.55.tar.gz
# mha4mysql-node-0.54.tar.gz

RUN apk add --update perl perl-dev musl-dev make gcc \
  && perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::mysql' \
  && perl -MCPAN -e "install Config::Tiny" \
  && perl -MCPAN -e "install Log::Dispatch" \
  && perl -MCPAN -e "install Parallel::ForkManager" \
  && cd /tmp \
  && tar -zxf mha4mysql-node-${MHA_NODE_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && cd mha4mysql-node-${MHA_NODE_VERSION}/ \
  && perl Makefile.PL \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && cd /tmp \
  && tar -zxf mha4mysql-manager-${MHA_MANAGER_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && cd mha4mysql-manager-${MHA_MANAGER_VERSION}/ \
  && perl Makefile.PL \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && apk del make gcc musl-dev perl-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/perl", "-de0"]
```